# Objective-C Basic Class question

Tags: objective-c, class, initialization, instance-variables

So I'm a bit rusty getting back into programming and I can't seem to find a good reference for understanding the structure for what I am trying to achieve. So, without further ado I am looking at creating and Class object such as.

```
#import Assets.h

@interface MainRecord: NSObject {
    Assets* assets;
    ...
}
...
@end
```

Having a class object within a class, do i need to initialize when the object is created in main? I want to make sure each instance created for MainRecord will always be associated with it's Assets.(in the future these will be written to a file) All of which is mainly for readability and ease of adding objects to this class.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend reading (at least parts of) [The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/), a guide published by Apple. The section called ["Defining a Class"](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html) will answer the bulk of your questions.

Basically, you *don't* initialize instance variables in `main()` — the class defines methods that handle its own variables. (This is common practice for [object-oriented programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming_language).) In Objective-C you initialize instance variables in an **`-(id)init`** method and release them in **`-(void)dealloc`** method to avoid leaking memory. For example, see all the **`-initWith...`** methods in [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/).